# Deploy iOS App With Secure String

Tags: ios7

In order to post some commands to Auth0 the https request must contain an authorization token. Auth0 says it's preferable to use a token generated by their dashboard than to generate the token in code. They advise to store the provided string securely in the app. I am wondering how to do that.

I am way out of my zone here, but at a high level I imagine that an iOS app is deployed as some sort of constant image/bundle. In order to write the token to the keychain on the user's device I have to embed the token in the image and then copy it to the keychain once the app is installed and running. But I don't see a way to remove the token from the image after the string is in the keychain.

There may be a facility for doing this type of thing that I am not able to find. My naive solution for the moment is to store the string in a global variable, then copy the string to the keychain and set the global variable to nil. But I'm not sure that really does the job.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can your app get this token from their dashboard at run-time?  (You don't say whether it's per app, per user....)

Comment: Getting a token is not yet included in their public api. The token seems to be a per app token as it never expires and is good for all requests from any installation of my app for  the specified service.